# How to save textarea data when click outside the textarea using ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am using froala editor and i want text in text area of editor saved when user clicks outside that textarea using Ajax i am new in ajax id of content editor is `#id_content`

This is my form part in django

```
<form method="POST" id="froala_form" class="PageForm _inputHolder">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="_alignRight posR _saveBTNOut">
      <button type="submit" class="_btn btnPrimery">Save as Draft</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what i have tried but not getting any proper logic

```
   function loadDoc(){
      var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange=function{
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
          var x = document.getElementById("id_content");
          x.addEventListener("click", ajaxsavefunc);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET",'url', true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function ajaxsavefunc(xhttp) {
     document.getElementById("froala_form").innerHTML = editor.html.get()
   }
```

Comment: check data on loss focus from teaxt area and if have value then save it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of how to use blur(when user click outside of field) in Jquery.

Basically this example will return a alert with the value of input when user click in the field and click out of the field.

```
<form method="post" action="" >
   <input type="text" id="test" value="123">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
$(function () {
  $('#test').blur(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById("test").value;
    var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "someaction.do?action=saveData",
      data: {input: x},
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: but i have to use ajax

Comment: @AnkushRasgon ajax will be used to post the data. Once you select value from input you can post it to you server. I add example method to post data with Ajax  after app select the value of input on blur. Regards.